# SQL Change format of datetime to specific style

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a datetime value to a specific format, but noe of the style codes seem to do what I want.  I tried the SQLUSA post on style codes, but none of them are quite right.

I have a column where the date/time is stored as **yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss (24 hour time)**

I have a select statement were I want to take this column, but express the date as: **mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM**

The closest I've come is:

```
CONVERT(varchar,[datetimecolum],22) AS [newcolumnname]
```

but that only gives me a 2 digit year, not a century year (yyyy).

Any ideas? I'm totally lost. :(

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, datetime fields are not stored in a specific string format, or but as a serial number. So what you see on screen is not what is stored but rather your database tool's default rendering of the date. Secondly why are you doing this in SQL? If you're passing the value to an application, make the conversion there from a native type. Thirdly, I don't think 22 is a valid conversion code in TSQL. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, for more info.

Comment: Having posted a solution which will work in SQL, I couldn't agree more with magos. Why not let your application handle display formatting?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a query used in an SSIS project at my office, and the change "has" to be made on my end in the database. :(

Answer (score 1):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Judging by all the other formats listed, it would infer just add 100 to the format number to get "with century" (yyyy).

Although according to the documentation (and my tests) there is no format 22 (or 122) - so you'll have to combine two other formats to get exactly what you need:

`CONVERT(varchar,[datetimecolum],101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,[datetimecolum],108) AS [newcolumnname]`

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/639b4/6)

Comment: Hmm, when I try that it's close, but I get the date twice.

Comment: You shouldn't do - see the demo!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Even clunkier than my original, but it works, except you won't get leading zeros for hours or minutes. You could modify this code to do that as well, but it will get really messy then, so I leave that to you  ;-)

In other words, if the date + time is

3/1/2012 10:01:35 PM,

you will instead get:

3/1/2012 10:1:35 PM

Irritating, eh?

Anyway, here you go. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT dt.ID,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT DATEPART(HH, mt.TheDate)
                FROM MyTable AS mt 
                WHERE mt.ID = dt.ID 
                AND (DATEPART(HH, mt.TheDate)) > 12)
    THEN
        (SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar,(MONTH(dt.TheDate))) + '/' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DAY(dt.TheDate))) + '/' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(YEAR(dt.TheDate))) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(HH, dt.TheDate)-12) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DATEPART(mi, dt.TheDate))) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DATEPART( ss, dt.TheDate))) + ' PM')
    ELSE
        (SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar,(MONTH(dt.TheDate))) + '/' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DAY(dt.TheDate))) + '/' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(YEAR(dt.TheDate))) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(HH, dt.TheDate)) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DATEPART(mi, dt.TheDate))) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar,(DATEPART( ss, dt.TheDate))) + ' AM') END As FullDate
FROM MyTable AS dt
```

Comment: Any idea how I could then do the time?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it

```
  select stuff(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),22),7,2,
  CAST( DATEPART(yyyy,getdate()) as CHAR(4)))
```

This is close but no AM PM

```
  select convert(varchar(100),getdate(),22), 
   + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(mm,getdate()) as CHAR(2))
   + '/' + CAST( DATEPART(dd,getdate()) as CHAR(2))
   + '/' + CAST( DATEPART(yyyy,getdate()) as CHAR(4))
   + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(HH,getdate()) as CHAR(2))
   + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(mi,getdate()) as CHAR(2))
   + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(ss,getdate()) as CHAR(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in 2 parts and you need to use stuff to remove millisecond.I will update if find an other way to get rid of millisecond

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)+' '+STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109),14),9,4,'')
```

output : `09/13/2012 11:15:21PM`

Edit: incase you want space before AM/PM then use `' '` instead of `''` in stuff

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)+' '+STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109),14),9,4,' ')
```

output : `09/13/2012 11:15:59 PM`